# Unable to install the tidyverse

Tags: r, linux, ubuntu

There is no package called 'tidyverse' is the error message I get after doing this:

```
install.packages('tidyverse', dependencies = T); 
install.packages('DBI', dependencies = T);
library(DBI);
library(tidyverse);
```

I use Ubuntu 18.04 and Rstudio.

Could anyone sort me out here, please?

Comment: Try removing the semicolons

Comment: What was the full output from just running the first line?

Comment: Running the first line I get a long return. However, the first error message conserns 'curl': 'No package 'libcurl' found.

Answer (score 4):

The default setup in R on Linux is to compile packages from source since CRAN only provides binaries for macOS and Windows. **This is not the recommended way to install packages on Ubuntu**. As pointed out by @DirkEddelbuettel in his edit to his answer, you can use `r2u` and `bspm` to obtain binaries for all CRAN packages. This will require initial setup but result in a much better user experience. If you insist on compiling the `tidyverse` yourself, my old answer remains below.

### Old answer

`tidyverse` has external dependencies that cannot be installed through R and that aren't preinstalled in Ubuntu. Install the following packages via the terminal:

```
sudo apt install libcurl4-openssl-dev libssl-dev libxml2-dev
```

Run `install.packages("tidyverse")` again after that.

You can find more help regarding this [here](https://blog.zenggyu.com/en/post/2018-01-29/installing-r-r-packages-e-g-tidyverse-and-rstudio-on-ubuntu-linux/).

Comment: Still working solution for ubuntu 22.04, Thanks

Comment: yes, it still works, but this is not the recommended way to install packages on ubuntu. I have updated my post to reflect that

Answer (score 4):

You may find [this blog post and associated video](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/blog/2019/06/09#022_rocker_and_ppas) useful -- it shows *how to install all of tidyverse on Ubuntu directly from prebuilt binaries with one command*.

In short, that is what PPAs are good for.  The associate slides have the relevant commands.

And once you do the required step of adding the two PPAs and running `sudo apt-get update` (again, both detailed in the slides) then *all it takes* is a single `sudo apt-get install r-cran-tidyverse` as the video shows.

Added bonus: because you install *binaries* that pre-made it is the fastest possible installation.

*Edit three years later:*  We now have [r2u](http://eddelbuettel.github.io/r2u/) which thanks to its use of [bspm](https://cloud.r-project.org/package=bspm) plus its *complete* set of CRAN binaries lets you just use `install.packages("tidyverse")` to install *all* packages as binaries along with *all* dependencies in a matter of seconds as shown in a few gifs on the site, my blog, and elsewhere. Plus anybody can try it in the browser via [gitpod](https://www.gitpod.io/) from the [r2u site](http://eddelbuettel.github.io/r2u/).

Comment: this is close to a link-only answer ... I think it'd be better to either relegate it to a comment, or cut & paste critical info (the tl;dr version) here ...

Comment: I am at an airport typing on a phone. Plus I have trying to explain this very point for fifteen years. Hence the video  and slides.

Comment: That's understandable. I'd still classify your original version as a link-only answer. (Most of the criticism of link-only answers (e.g. [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)) is based on the possibility of link rot ...)  I think your edits provide the required context.